# Maven/Scala: Filename is too long

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven

This error occurs if I try to compile the scala project with maven.

```
[ERROR] error: File name too long
[ERROR] two errors found
```

Already found the hint that maybe the problem lies in the encryption in Ubuntu. So I minimized the class file to the minimum 72

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <args>
      <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
      <arg>72</arg>
    </args>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>scala-compile-first</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Nevertheless the error is still there and I have no idea why it is still appears.
It is an eclipse maven plugin and I use at least scala 2.10.3 in Ubuntu 15.04.
How do I resolve this?

**Edit**: The filename is 10 characters long and it is in a package which could occur as a very long absolut path name. I tried to change the path to a shorter absolut path and shorten the classname without solving the problem.

Comment: what is your filename?

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu. The only option I've found is to move to non-encrypting folder

Comment: Add some details regarding the problem, like the filename for example.

Comment: The filename is 10 characters long. So, there are other files in the same package which don't fire error.

Comment: @nyavro This is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problems

```
<groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2</version>
<configuration>
      <args>
         <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
         <arg>140</arg>
      </args>
</configuration>
```

worked for me. Seems that it is different maven plugin.

Comment: Already tried this solution but without solving the problem. Don't know why this doesn't help